# Swapping property values between objects

Tags: user-interface, matlab, figure

I have created two textboxes via annotation(.) in a figure. Most of their properties have been defined; and the callback function enables drag and drop motion in the window. I created a uicontextmenu for the boxes. On right click a list of functions can be chosen from for subsequent action.

One of the actions I am trying to add involves swapping strings between the two boxes. I need to get the string of the box I currently right-clicked, which should swap with the string in the box I subsequently left-click. Can I get advice on how to go about extending the uimenu function so that it registers the subsequent left-click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually store the last clicked box. If you are using GUIDE to design your GUI, use the `handles` structure which gets passed around to callback functions. Otherwise if you programmatically generate the components, then nested callback functions have access to variables defined inside their enclosing functions.

#### EDIT

Here is a complete example: right-click and select "Swap" from context menu, then choose the other textbox to swap strings with (left-click). Note that I had to disable/enable the textboxes in-between the two steps to be able to fire the ButtonDownFcn (see this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-158CEG/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-158CEG) for an explanation)

```
function myTestGUI
    %# create GUI
    hLastBox = [];          %# handle to textbox initiating swap
    isFirstTime = true;     %# show message box only once
    h(1) = uicontrol('style','edit', 'string','1', 'position',[100 200 60 20]);
    h(2) = uicontrol('style','edit', 'string','2', 'position',[400 200 60 20]);
    h(3) = uicontrol('style','edit', 'string','3', 'position',[250 300 60 20]);
    h(4) = uicontrol('style','edit', 'string','4', 'position',[250 100 60 20]);

    %# create context menu and attach to textboxes
    hCMenu = uicontextmenu;
    uimenu(hCMenu, 'Label','Swap String...', 'Callback', @swapBeginCallback);
    set(h, 'uicontextmenu',hCMenu)

    function swapBeginCallback(hObj,ev)
        %# save the handle of the textbox we right clicked on
        hLastBox = gco;

        %# we must disable textboxes to be able to fire the ButtonDownFcn
        set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn',@swapEndCallback)
        set(h, 'Enable','off')

        %# show instruction to user
        if isFirstTime
            isFirstTime = false;
            msgbox('Now select textbox you want to switch string with');
        end
    end
    function swapEndCallback(hObj,ev)
        %# re-enable textboxes, and reset ButtonDownFcn handler
        set(h, 'Enable','on')
        set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn',[])

        %# swap strings
        str = get(gcbo,'String');
        set(gcbo, 'String',get(hLastBox,'String'))
        set(hLastBox, 'String',str)
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Would the leftClick function have to be asssigned to the ButtonDownFcn property of a box object? With the rightClick function used as the mechanic that swaps the strings.